# Centering UIViews and scaling using size classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, size-classes

I am trying to layout a UIViewController with several smaller UIViews in it (The blue squares).

Through the magic of photoshop here is how I am trying to get the blue squares to appear on different size devices.

[image]

Centered and contained between the two UILabels.

Though the UIViews do not scale, or they overlap, or they are off centered. I am trying to do this with Interface Builder.

[image]

[image]

***Is this possible to accomplish? I can't seem to find a way of having my cake and eating it too.***

Unfortunately I am using size classes as I had a UIScollView in another ViewController I need to layout so a size class was created.

Comment: u can create multiple table cell and call those in indexpath row

Comment: Have you tried `UIStackView` to manage your layout?

Comment: @Losiowaty I need to be able to support back to iOS 7